# asp.net and windows workflow foundation 4

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation

Ive been tasked with creating a intranet system that handles Employee requests for hardware, training, marketing and potentially other types.  Each request will be initially approved by their line manager before moving up the ladder to the owners of the budgets these requests are assigned to.

With this in mind ive been doing some research on WF and to me this seems like the logical choice for developing it. My only problem is i cant seem to find any decent tutorials for asp.net.  I wont be using MVC as we havent adopted this yet.  Anyone know of any decent links using asp.net 4.0 and wf 4.0 together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have a blog post on this [ASP.NET WF4 / WCF and Async Calls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/03/21/asp-net-wf4-wcf-and-async-calls.aspx)